# Javascript arrray of object key-value switching

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reverse, key-value

So I have this homework and I'm stuck with this part. Basically my data is like this

```
const universities = [
  {
    School: 'Harvard',
    Country: ['USA']
  },
  {
    School: 'Oxford',
    Country: ['UK']
  },
  {
    School: 'MIT',
    Country: ['USA']
  },
  {
    School: 'Cambridge',
    Country: ['UK']
  },
  {
    School: 'IS',
    Country: ['Germany', 'UK', 'USA']
  },
  {
    School: 'BIT',
    Country: ['Germany']
  },
]
```

And the output that I am looking for is like this

```
const countryOfOperation = {
    Germany: ['IS', 'BIT'],
    UK: ['Oxford', 'Cambridge', 'IS'],
    USA: ['Harvard', 'MIT', 'IS']
  }
```

I was able to solve it but my function looks really awful.

```
const reverse = (universities) => {
  let arr = universities;
  let obj = {};
  let arrs = [];

  arr.forEach((el) => {
    if (!el.Country) return;
    el.Country.forEach((els) => {
      if (arrs.includes(els)) return;
      arrs.push(els);
    });
  });
  arrs.forEach((country) => {
    let countryArr = [];
    arr.forEach((el) => {
      if (!el.Country) return;
      el.Country.find((selected) => {
        if (selected === country) {
          countryArr.push(el.School);
          obj[selected] = countryArr;
        }
      });
    });
  });  
  return obj;
};
```

Can someone help me in fixing my code? I will really appreciate it. I spent too much time already with this and Im so stressed.

Comment: If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Comment: Why is the output an array with a single element? Why not just return the only element of that array.

Comment: @Aplet123 Yes it is possible too but like I said I am already stressed with this and I am just a beginner student developer

Comment: "fixing my code" fixing how? What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to take only an object as result, because you have only a single item in the array.

Basically you nee two nested loops, one for the items of `universities` and another for `Country`.

Then another check is neccessary, if the property `country` does not exist. In this case assign an empty array to the property.

Finally push `School` to the property.

```js
const
    universities = [{ School: 'Harvard', Country: ['USA'] }, { School: 'Oxford', Country: ['UK'] }, { School: 'MIT', Country: ['USA'] }, { School: 'Cambridge', Country: ['UK'] }, { School: 'IS', Country: ['Germany', 'UK', 'USA'] }, { School: 'BIT', Country: ['Germany'] }],
    countryOfOperation = universities.reduce((accumulator, { School, Country }) => {
        Country.forEach(country => {
            if (!accumulator[country]) accumulator[country] = [];
            accumulator[country].push(School);
        });
        return accumulator;
    }, {});

console.log(countryOfOperation);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to accumulate the desired result-object starting with an empty object. Take for every object the Country and iterate with [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) over it. Look if in the accumulated object exists a property for this country. If not create one and add an Array with the School as element to it. Otherwise take this property and add to the array there the School as new element.

```js
const universities = [
  {
    School: 'Harvard',
    Country: ['USA']
  },
  {
    School: 'Oxford',
    Country: ['UK']
  },
  {
    School: 'MIT',
    Country: ['USA']
  },
  {
    School: 'Cambridge',
    Country: ['UK']
  },
  {
    School: 'IS',
    Country: ['Germany', 'UK', 'USA']
  },
  {
    School: 'BIT',
    Country: ['Germany']
  },
];

let res = universities.reduce((acc, {School, Country}) => {
    Country.forEach(cnt => {
        if (acc[cnt]===undefined) {
            acc[cnt] = [School];
        } else 
            acc[cnt].push(School);
    });
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: how is this different from the already existing answer?

Comment: @The Fool - You are right it's nearly the same. I didn't saw Nina's answer as I wrote the code and posted it here (as I started there wasn't any answer here). By this similarity you see if you are writing short code there aren't so much possibilities.

Comment: @The Fool - The only noticable difference is in the if-statement: I create the array with the element and return and Nina creates empty array and pushes it afterwards. I look the last month often at Nina's (and others)  sollutions to learn more because they are (most) very clear and understoodable, so I use often similiar but also sometimes completly different approaches

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be as simple as below:

```
const countryOfOperation = []

universities.forEach(university => {
    const { Country, School } = university

    Country.forEach(country => {
        if (countryOfOperation[country] === undefined) {
            countryOfOperation[country] = []
        }

        if (!countryOfOperation[country].includes(School)) {
            countryOfOperation[country].push(School)
        }
    })
})

console.log(countryOfOperation)
```